# Nilpotency of an element and its prime divisor.

Tags: abstract-algebra

An element $x$ in a ring $R$ is said to be nilpotent if $x^m = 0$ for some $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

If $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an integer show that the element $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z}$ is nilpotent if and only every prime divisors of $n$ are prime divisors of $a$. I have done this proof. It is given below.

As $\bar{a}$ is nilpotent in $\mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z}$ $\exists$ an element $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $\bar{a}^k \equiv 0$ (mod $n$). So $n|a^k$. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$ then $p|a^k$ i.e. $p|a$. Conversely if every prime divisors of $a$ be a prime divisor of $n$. Then by Fundamental theorem of arithmetic we may calculate an integer $k$ s.t. $n | a^k$. So $a^k \equiv 0$ (mod $n$). Hence the proof. Please check if my attempt is accurate.

My doubt is here. Take $n = 72$. Here prime divisors are $2$ and $3$ only. So all the integer $a$ $0 < a <72$ multiple of both $2$ and $3$ will be a nilpotent element. But $\bar{2}$ is a nilpotent element as $\bar{2}^{36} = 0$ but $\bar{2}$ is not a multiple of $3$. I can not understand the fact. Is there any mistake on the statement of the result?

Thank your for your help. If it is already discussed please mention the link only.

Source : Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foot , 2nd edition Page 232 Exercise 13 b.

Comment: Did you by any means use a $32$-bit binary computer to compute $2^{36}$? That would give $0$, which is divisible by $3$ (and by $72$). Without such computational errors, $2^{36}$ should not have acquired a factor$~3$, and hence not be divisible by$~72$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^{36}\equiv 64^6\equiv (-8)^6\equiv 2^{18}\equiv  64^3\equiv  -8^3\equiv -2^9 \equiv 64\cdot 8\equiv64\not\equiv 0\mod72$.

Comment: You are welcome.